# How do you call the Amplience handlebars service with data parameters

Tags: amplience-dynamic-content

I want to call the Amplience handlebars service with additional parameters that I can then use with my content rendering.

tried with
https://c1.adis.ws/v1/content/jwdemo/content-item/32101dfb-f1aa-4b35-a69d-724fa2275660?template=debug-content-asset&status=In-Progress

Nothing shows up - where in the content JSON should the parameters actually end up? How can I reference them in the handlebars code?

Answer (score 1):

Parameters can then be referenced from within your handlebars template. Parameters need to be name-spaced with 'crparam' in order to be recognised. I've updated your request

```
https://c1.adis.ws/v1/content/jwdemo/content-item/32101dfb-f1aa-4b35-a69d-724fa2275660?template=debug-content-asset&crparam.status=In-Progress
```

If you're trying to compare or add business logic then the example below shows what would be needed in your template using the crParam and eq helpers

```
{{#eq (crParam 'status'  .) 'In-Progress'}}
  Progressing...
{{else}}
  Do Nothing
{{/eq}}
```